# SSIS convert escaped character to asc(non printable characters)

Tags: sql, csv, ssis, escaping, non-printable

I use SSIS to migrate some csv files (from UNIX) into SQL. one csv file contains data like:

ID,Name,Desc

1,12345\t,12345\177

If the schema for Name or Desc must be varchar(6), then the migration will fail due to the non printable characters are presented as \t, \177...

How can I convert the escaped characters to non printable characters in SSIS?

\t to Char(9)

\177 to Char(127)

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use regular expressions regex.unescape to do this. I would suggest loading the assembly and doing it in SQL server using a temporary table, check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I ended up using openrowset to get the data into temp tables. The SSIS csv parser is just terrible. Then used regular expression to unescape the non printable characters.